# How can I set a new value for a cell as a float in pandas dataframe (Python) - The DataFrame rounds to integer when in nested for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

**FOUND SOLUTION: I needed to change datatype for dataframe:**

```
for p in periods:
  df['Probability{}'.format(p)] = 0
```

```
for p in periods:
  df['Probability{}'.format(p)] = float(0)
```

Alternatively do as in approved answer below.

---

I am asserting new values for cells as floats but they are set as integers and I don't get why.
It is a part of a data mining project, which contains nested loops.

I am using Python 3.

I tried different modes of writing into a cell with pandas:
`df.at[index,col] = float(val)`, 
`df.set_value[index,col,float(val)]`, and 
`df[col][index] = float(val)` but none of them delivered a solution. The output I got was:

```
In: print(df[index][col])

Out: 0
```

```
In: print(val)

Out: 0.4774410939826658
```

Here is a simplified version of the loop

```
periods = [7,30,90,180]

for p in periods:
  df['Probability{}'.format(p)] = 0        

for i in range(len(df.index)):
   for p in periods:
       if i >= p - 1:

          # Getting relevant data and computing value 
          vals = [df['Close'][j] for j in range(i - p, i)]
          probability = (len([j for j in vals if j>0])/len(vals))

          # Asserting value to cell in pd.dataframe          
          df.at[df.index[i], 'Probability{}'.format(p)] = float(probability)
```

I don't get why pandas.DataFrame are changing float to integer and rounds up or down. When I asserted values to cells in console directly I did not experience any problems.

Is there any work arounds or solutions to this problem?

I had no problem before nesting a for loop for periods to avoid hard coding a lot of trivial code.

NB: It also seems that if I factorize, e.g. with `100 * val = new_val`, it do only factorize the rounded number. So if I multiplied `100*val = new_val = 0` because the number is rounded down to `0`.

I also tried to change datatype for the dataframe:

```
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

All the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a problem with incorrect data types in your dataframe. Your last attempt at converting the whole `df` was probably very close. Try and use

```
df['Close'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Close'], downcast="float")
```